# What's the name of the problem that relates to optimizing closures on a stack-based system?

Tags: optimization, functional-programming, closures

I remember hearing about a general optimization problem that relates to function closures, stating that in general it's difficult to optimize the creation of a closure using only stack-based memory management. Do any of you remember the name of this optimization problem, possibly with an example or link to relevant page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking of the [upward funarg problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funarg_problem#Upwards_funarg_problem).

Comment: That was it! I was looking at the Wikipedia's article on Closures, but didn't see a good link to the funarg article.  It's there, but is given without comment. I'll go fix that...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're thinking of [*escape analysis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis).

It concerns the distinction between what the Lisp community calls its two kinds of [*extent*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_e.htm#extent): [*dynamic extent*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_d.htm#dynamic_extent) and [*indefinite extent*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_i.htm#indefinite_extent). Objects of the former can be stack-allocated, while the latter cannot, as their lifetime likely exceeds the scope of their allocation.

Comment: Definitely an interesting problem as well!

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of [escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis)?